# Convert a dict object to nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking for how to create nested list from dictionary.
Here is the given Dictionary.

```
Dict={'Jason Seifer': ['Ruby Foundations', 'Ruby on Rails Forms', 'Technology Foundations'], 'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections'],'Jason Bourne':['black berry','mango','potato','oli','key'],'fruits':['cherry','pineapple','banana','coconut']}
```

Excepted output:

```
[['Jason Bourne', 5], ['Kenneth Love', 2], ['fruits', 4], ['Jason Seifer', 3]]
```

Here order doesn't matter

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding this question in the context of the title ... Where does `C++` come into this question at all?  What are you confused about exactly?

Comment: @mgilson, it doesn't. Seems like the usual shot in the dark to try & get the question noticed.

Comment: @StoryTeller - "One Weird Trick for creating a nested list - programmers hate it!" :P

Answer (score 5):

With a simple comprehension:

```
result = [[k, len(v)] for k,v in Dict.items()]
```

Comment: How to make it without using  .items() but nested loops ?

Comment: @user6619642 -- Why do you want nested for loops?  If you really want to avoid `.items()`, you can do `[[k, len(Dict[k])] for k in Dict]` or you can expand that out into a vanilla `for` loop, but no matter how you slice it, no _nesting_ is necessary.

Comment: The only way a nested loop would be necessary is if you can't use `len()` and must count the items yourself, which should never happen.